# Infer string literal type in an array without `as const`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that accepts an array of `keys`, and then passes one of those `keys` to the `children` render prop.

```
type PagerKeys = Readonly<[string, string, ...string[]]>; // needs to be at least 2 items

interface PagerProps<Keys extends PagerKeys> {
    children: (
        props: {
            currentKey: Keys[number]
        }
    ) => ReactNode;
    keys: Keys;
}

function Pager<Keys extends PagerKeys>({
    children, keys
}: PagerProps<Keys>) {
    const [currentKey, setCurrentKey] = useState<Keys[number]>(keys[0]);

    return children({
        currentKey
    });
}
```

I'm able to type check if the `currentKey` in the render prop matches `keys` by adding `as const` to the `keys` prop. (`PagerKeys` above is `Readonly` for that reason).

```
<Pager keys={['a', 'b'] as const}>
    {({currentKey}) => {
        if (currentKey === 'a') {}
        if (currentKey === 'lalala') {} // throws error as it should because 'lalala' is not a key
        ...
    }}
</Pager>
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to infer the string literal in `keys` without adding `as const`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mA8V1N) using [a `const` type parameter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz woah, this should work but it seems to only work with > Typescript 5.0. What would the solution be if it's not possible for me to upgrade Typescript version?

Comment: ! You have a dependency on not using the latest TS version?  That should be included in the question (and keep in mind that being stuck on an older TS version is not going to age well).  What version are you allowed to use?

Comment: @jcalz my bad, ignore my previous comment. I thought I had a dependency on a specific version. Let's go with your answer! Thank you!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance; it is now my bedtime so it will probably be in 8 or 9 hours.

Comment: FWIW you could write the same thing without using a `const` type parameter: https://tsplay.dev/wgvL0W

Comment: @vr. Please add it as an answer so others can see this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript 5.0 introduced [`const` type parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters) that let you add a `const` modifier to type parameters to ask the compiler for the same sort of inference you'd get if someone used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  This makes it easy for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function implementers to ask for `as const`-like behavior without having to use more obscure tricks (such as those described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680)).

In your case the change is as simple as

```
function Pager<const K extends PagerKeys>({
    // ------> ^^^^^
    children, keys
}: PagerProps<K>) {
    const [currentKey, setCurrentKey] = useState<K[number]>(keys[0]);

    return children({
        currentKey
    });
}
```

And now when you call

```
<Pager keys={['a', 'b']}>
    {({ currentKey }) => {
        if (currentKey === 'a') { }
        if (currentKey === 'lalala') { } // throws error as it should because 'lalala' is not a key
        return null!
    }}
</Pager>
```

The compiler infers the type parameter as `readonly ["a", "b"]` as desired:

```
// (property) PagerProps<readonly ["a", "b"]>.keys: readonly ["a", "b"]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-tmwErm2rqrrDcb9nQA4HzcQTASSRg83YAHczAZ2FA4OgzBU4OR5hBSMscqhMOgKAwuEPB0nymZbBB4OgYyY2zM3R7klv7ABCEPIpzxUVZkT0zb7CUDHUH5RXFSUFBsBw1DgFwACJ0FgkhYOyWCYkCW0NgguxHBg+DELgZDUNEIA)

Answer (score 1):

Pre-5.0, this was still possible using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to infer the strings as literal types:

```
interface PagerProps<Keys extends PagerKeys> {
    children: (props: { currentKey: Keys[number] }) => any;
    keys: [...Keys]; // ✨
}
```

This is the *only* change necessary!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAERTo4DGMVA3AFCiSxwBKdjp5SjT5M2rGAE8wBAAo4A5uigBpdBNRwAvDzoATCADsANhIA8AbVQwowA-IA0cKzbuOAdB+e355gLq+APmY4AHoQuAN0dF0NGAg4ACMCPDgjOis4ACY4YHwQVFZ2A3woEgZZBSUZcjBUU1V1OHQAD3wDGLg5RRU1VADEVjghuHoAC2AjXVoDAC44AAowGtQ5pHpkKGmYBrmG1HMDZBAkqF8iAEotfpwDCTZhuABrXrnzDzc93zZCQpJkA0YwEMnUqUHqvSarXQ7Q0XSUewC8zW40m00cz0ahDmcKg1QgtXB6gClwQg2G9EMGXM6020O2akcGBgAGENlsGmdtGgsLh8IT9odjkpAvMMfsAAy+c5iB60GAbAwjFFTaFIskPIY09kM9UXb6FUw4p69TQIcxUHBURxUBJUXyEAK6hBIkZsukNC5XAYa4bAEgLLXutRaTTaC1UEk-H1DXUPP0Bt3FD2hsNGHBptMRxDEMJwGCjcgAdw0SnIUDgOA0uScowgyEmiXQ9Bw3LgAHIM+mcG2choDBB4DhjRJCtG4HKFRF60YAIT3YaEH6mEI4oKsIA)